# Generate unique and random samples of a given list in Python for a given amount of times?

Tags: python

Lets say `L=[1,2,3,4,5]`

How can I create 4 (or maximum of `len(L)`!) unique random orders of L?

Expected result should look like this:

```
[[2,1,3,4,5],[5,3,2,1,4],[4,3,2,1,5],[5,1,3,2,4]
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Look at [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) and [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: would this `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4],
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5],
[1, 2, 4, 5, 3]]` be valid result for you?

Comment: I did not look at itertools.
I tried random.choices but the problem was omitting the repeated random samples. There is no guarantee that two randomly generated samples are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly standard approach: pick random samples and throw away duplicates for a small sample, or partial shuffle if you're generating a sample that covers most of the sample space.

```
import itertools
import math
import random

def n_random_permutations(n, l):
    if n * 3 < math.factorial(len(l)):
        # rejection sampling
        # generate samples and throw them away if we already picked them.
        samples = set()

        while len(samples) < n:
            sample = list(l)
            random.shuffle(sample)
            samples.add(tuple(sample))

        samples = list(samples)
        random.shuffle(samples)
        return samples
    else:
        # generate every possible permutation and pick n of them.
        permutations = list(itertools.permutations(l))
        return random.sample(permutations, n)
```

Comment: Good alternative for larger arrays! One thing to consider though is that `math.factorial(len(l))` might go out of range due to multiplication by `0.3` which casts it to `float`. Doing `if n/0.3 < math.factorial(len(l))` would solve overflow error for larger lists...

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python) post, you can use `itertools` to generate all possible permutations of the list:

```
all_perms = list(itertools.permutations(L))
```

then if you only want 4 random choices (without replacement) of all possible permutations, you can do something like:

```
random.sample(all_perms, k=4)
```

Comment: That's going to generate a lot more permutations than necessary, though. That might not be a big deal with a length-4 list, but it's completely infeasible for something like length-20.

Comment: Yes, I was about to comment on your answer... its good to have a more efficient alternative for larger lists. I wonder if this can be solved with numpy.